# How to get data into execute method in quartz.net scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm using the quartz.net scheduler to schedule my tasks in c# mvc code.

I want to start one method on application start that fetches data from the database and add it to the scheduler to run at a specific time.

My simple example scheduler is working fine when I use it to write a "hello" word. But when I write a method to get data from the database into an execute method I'm unable to create a parameterized constructor for that service and interface.

How can I do it please?
My code is:

```
        // GET: /Schedule/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
             // construct a scheduler factory
            ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

            // get a scheduler, start the schedular before triggers or anything else
            IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
            sched.Start();

            // create job
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SimpleJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .Build();

            // create trigger
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(2).RepeatForever())
                .Build();


            // Schedule the job using the job and trigger 
            sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            //    _QueuedMessagesSendTask.SendEmail();

            return View();
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// SimpleJOb is just a class that implements IJOB interface. It implements just one method, Execute method
    /// </summary>
    public class SimpleJob : IJob
    {
        private readonly XITDataContext _xitDataContext;

        public SimpleJob(XITDataContext xitDataContext)
        {
            this._xitDataContext = xitDataContext;
        }

        void IJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var data = _xitDataContext.Invoice.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the problem? did you get any error?

Comment: no. i dont get error. still i am checking this link that i think it solve my problem

Comment: http://codein60seconds.blogspot.in/2015/08/quartz-with-ninject-dependency-injection.html

Comment: If you're using DI with Ninject that's the right way, but if not, you just may want to create the data context instance in the SimpleJob class constructor. If it's an isolated object, you can pass additional information as parameters using the JobDataMap in the JobDetail. You can read more about it [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html)